# Add CKEditor to Symfony CMF and Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, sonata-admin, symfony-cmf

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to implement CKEditor with Symfony CMF. I have a working implementation but I'm not sure it's the correct way to do it.

What I have done is override the `sonata_admin` edit template with:

**config.yml**

```
sonata_admin:
    ...
    templates:
        edit: MyBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
```

**edit.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Then I've added the `ckeditor` class to my textarea fields in the admin panels.

Whilst this works I am aware that CMF has a `CreateBundle` which contains CKEditor, but I haven't found any documentation on how this can be linked to the admin pages. I'm wondering whether that has any benefits over my current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this PR as inspiration:
https://github.com/symfony-cmf/SimpleCmsBundle/pull/149